# How can I remove this rusted single hole faucet?

Tags: plumbing, stuck, rust

How can I remove this rusted single hole faucet?
I've tried pentrating oil, despite the smell, I've removed
the two lock screws.  The thing won't budge.

I feel like I've put a lot of pressure on the nut anyway.  Is a basin wrench the appropriate tool for this nut?  I'm concerned the nut is so thin, a basin wrench won't be able to get a bite.

It does not budge or spin at all.

[image]

Comment: If you have the room would try a hammer and punch.  A few good wacks after penetrating oil might loosen it up.  It has four wings/knobs on it to use.

Comment: Get a spanner wrench.  i.e. https://www.harborfreight.com/adjustable-pin-wrench-36554.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=17890471891&campaignid=17890471891&utm_content=146321459224&adsetid=146321459224&product=36554&store=147&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIgqjt9-n1-wIVDabICh1NBQCjEAQYAyABEgLtkPD_BwE

Comment: There are different types of penetrating oil. Most people reach for WD-40 (which is designed more to protect against rusting in the first place) first. I find that to be fairly ineffective on rusted automotive bolts. I find PB Blaster to be significantly more effective against rust. There are other brands of penetrating fluids available, too, mostly at auto parts stores.

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to just pull the sink. But first off : Get the covers out of the way. Cut the pipes out of the way. Get you with a basin wrench under there, and another person with a pipe wrench on top. Then do a bunch of muffled swearing at each other.

Answer (score 1):

Spray with WD40 you might have to work it in by spraying, letting it set.

Then use channel locks one on upper and lower. Have one braced so that while your on opposite side of sink or whatever, it is got something solid to keep it from twirling.

If you don't need the faucet, as in replacing, use a metal dreml grinder, sawz all & cut it off. Be careful not to damage a finish of something you can't buff or use a wheel brush to smooth out.

You could try CLR put it on with maybe a paint brush or spray it.

Comment: How would cutting it off help?  There's presumably a flange above, and a nut below.  Only above can be cut, and then only above the flange.

Comment: You can cut it off If your replacing the faucet. Depends on how rusted it is. I have had it twice where Nothing would take it off short if a plumber and even then not.

If your having a water leak, shut the water off until you can get what you need tomorrow. If your in a fix cause you cant afford a faucet, they can be 100-200 the go to Habitat to Humanity. Or use a bucket and heat water until you can replace it.

Comment: My plumbing general rule of thumb is....if it's 20 years old it (usually) needs to be cut off. But this is not a hard and fast rule. How you cut depends on what you're presented with. Sometimes I've had to slice, dice and drill off faucets in sections....

Comment: It's 3-4 years old, a Phister, and it's failed.  The company supplied a warranty replacement.  But if I cut it off, how does that help me remove the stuck nut?